# draw canvas lines to all divs with the same class name

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am making a document that will build a tree type graph through user input. I am trying to connect styled divs to the relative div they branched from with canvas lines. 
I have been using `.getBoundingClientRect()` to get the positions, but the divs are static with inline-block, so every time a new one is added, the whole structure changes.

So, here is my attempt at a 'for loop' that is called every time a new branch is made, to re-draw all of the canvas lines.

```
var lines = function(){
    var blocks=document.getElementsByClassName('block');
for (i=1;i<blocks.length-1;i++){
    var blockDiv = blocks[i]
    var offset = blockDiv.getBoundingClientRect();
    var xa = offset.left+40;
    var ya = offset.top+40;
    var blockFrom = blockDiv.parentNode.parentNode.previousSibling;
    var offsets = blockFrom.getBoundingClientRect();
    var yb = offsets.top+40;
    var xb = offsets.left+40;
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.moveTo(xa,ya);
    ctx.lineTo(xb,yb);
    ctx.stroke();   
  }
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MarkTA/kczac9z0/1/) so you can see the general structure of the divs.

When the function is called, I get no canvas lines and a console error of
`166 Uncaught TypeError: blockDiv.parentNode.parentNode.previousSibling.getBoundingClientRect is not a function`


I am stumped on this one and would really appreciate the help.
I am new to canvas, javascript, and coding in general so any other constructive criticism would also be greatly appreciated. :)

Vanilla js only please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this:

> Gecko-based browsers insert text nodes into a document to represent
>   whitespace in the source markup. Therefore a node obtained, for
>   example, using Node.firstChild or Node.previousSibling may refer to a
>   whitespace text node rather than the actual element the author
>   intended to get.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling

Therefore, change this line:

```
var blockFrom = blockDiv.parentNode.parentNode.previousSibling;
```

to this:

```
var blockFrom = blockDiv.parentNode.parentNode.previousSibling.previousSibling;
```